# Generate CSV and Copy clipboard using datatables.net framework

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal: Generate CSV and Copy to clip board only those items which are checkbox selected.

Current condition: I have made two javascript codes one for selection but second part of code (which is commented) is for generate CSV and copy problem is second part not working and first part works however multi selects not works.

Jquery Framework used: https://datatables.net

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css">

  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
} );

////bellow code is for CSV and Copy option but this not work for only selected item

// if ($("#example").length) {
//        $("#example").DataTable({
//            dom: "Bfrtip",
//            buttons: [
//                {
//                    extend: "copy",
//                    className: "btn-sm"
//                    ,
//                    exportOptions: {
//                        columns: [5, 3, 4, 7, 6]
//                    }
//                },
//                {
//                    extend: "csv",
//                    className: "btn-sm"
//                    ,
//                    exportOptions: {
//                        columns: [5, 3, 4, 7, 6]
//                    }
//                },
//                {
//                    extend: "excel",
//                    className: "btn-sm",
//                    exportOptions: {
//                        columns: [5, 3, 4, 7, 6]
//                    }
//                },
//                {
//                    extend: "pdfHtml5",
//                    className: "btn-sm"
//                    ,
//                    exportOptions: {
//                        columns: [5, 3, 4, 7, 6]
//                    }
//                },

//            ],
//            responsive: true,
//            "pageLength": 100
//        });
//     }


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could get multiple select and then print selected option. Hope this helps.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.18/pdfmake.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.print.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>

    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>$433,060</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Airi Satou</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                    <td>$162,700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>$372,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>$137,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>55</td>
                    <td>$327,900</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>39</td>
                    <td>$205,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>$103,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>$90,560</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                    <td>Support Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>$342,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>36</td>
                    <td>$470,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                    <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>43</td>
                    <td>$313,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>19</td>
                    <td>$385,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Michael Silva</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>$198,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                    <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>$725,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Gloria Little</td>
                    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>$237,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>41</td>
                    <td>$132,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Dai Rios</td>
                    <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>35</td>
                    <td>$217,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                    <td>Development Lead</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>$345,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                    <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>40</td>
                    <td>$675,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                    <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td>$106,450</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>Sidney</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>$85,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                    <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>$1,200,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>42</td>
                    <td>$92,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>28</td>
                    <td>$357,650</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>28</td>
                    <td>$206,850</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Fiona Green</td>
                    <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>48</td>
                    <td>$850,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Shou Itou</td>
                    <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                    <td>$163,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Michelle House</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>Sidney</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>$95,400</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Suki Burks</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                    <td>$114,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                    <td>Technical Author</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>$145,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                    <td>Team Leader</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>$235,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                    <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>$324,050</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Unity Butler</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>$85,675</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>51</td>
                    <td>$164,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                    <td>Secretary</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>41</td>
                    <td>$109,850</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                    <td>Financial Controller</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>62</td>
                    <td>$452,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>$136,200</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                    <td>Director</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>65</td>
                    <td>$645,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>$234,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>38</td>
                    <td>$163,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>$139,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Thor Walton</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>$98,540</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>$87,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                    <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>$138,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>$125,250</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>56</td>
                    <td>$115,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                    <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>43</td>
                    <td>$75,650</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>$145,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>$356,250</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Lael Greer</td>
                    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td>$103,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>$86,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Shad Decker</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>51</td>
                    <td>$183,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>29</td>
                    <td>$183,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'pdf', 'print',
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: 'Print selected',
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csv',
                    text: 'CSV selected',
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                }                    

            ],        
            columnDefs: [ {
                orderable: false,
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                targets:   0,
                checkboxes : {
                    selectRow : true
                }
            } ],
            select: {
                style:    'multi',
                selector: 'td:first-child'
            },
            order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]

        } );



    } );

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Print selected option prints only selected items this is correct but is it possible to do same with CSV and Copy? you are close to done. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did exactly the same thing as 'print selected' for 'csv selected'. Check if that works... It does not at my end.  I get blank file with no extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `bSelectedOnly` like this :

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sRowSelect": "multi",
            "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends": "csv",
                    "bSelectedOnly": true
                }
            ]
        }
    } );
} );
```

When `bSelectedOnly` option is set to true, the data gathered from the table will be from only the rows which are selected by the end user (using the sRowSelect option) - all other data will be discarded (i.e. not used in the save / copy). If no rows are selected, then all data is used.

You can similarly try for yourself for copy button also.

Answer (score 0):

I did as your goal. Please test the code bellow and let us know.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.18/pdfmake.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.print.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>

    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>$433,060</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Airi Satou</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                    <td>$162,700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>$372,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>$137,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>55</td>
                    <td>$327,900</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>39</td>
                    <td>$205,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>$103,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>$90,560</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                    <td>Support Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>$342,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>36</td>
                    <td>$470,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                    <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>43</td>
                    <td>$313,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>19</td>
                    <td>$385,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Michael Silva</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>$198,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                    <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>$725,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Gloria Little</td>
                    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>$237,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>41</td>
                    <td>$132,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Dai Rios</td>
                    <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>35</td>
                    <td>$217,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                    <td>Development Lead</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>$345,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                    <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>40</td>
                    <td>$675,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                    <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td>$106,450</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>Sidney</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>$85,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                    <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>$1,200,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>42</td>
                    <td>$92,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>28</td>
                    <td>$357,650</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>28</td>
                    <td>$206,850</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Fiona Green</td>
                    <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>48</td>
                    <td>$850,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Shou Itou</td>
                    <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                    <td>$163,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Michelle House</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>Sidney</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>$95,400</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Suki Burks</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                    <td>$114,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                    <td>Technical Author</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>$145,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                    <td>Team Leader</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>$235,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                    <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>$324,050</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Unity Butler</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>$85,675</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>51</td>
                    <td>$164,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                    <td>Secretary</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>41</td>
                    <td>$109,850</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                    <td>Financial Controller</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>62</td>
                    <td>$452,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>$136,200</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                    <td>Director</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>65</td>
                    <td>$645,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>$234,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>38</td>
                    <td>$163,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>$139,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Thor Walton</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>$98,540</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>$87,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                    <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>$138,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>$125,250</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>56</td>
                    <td>$115,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                    <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>43</td>
                    <td>$75,650</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>$145,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>$356,250</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Lael Greer</td>
                    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td>$103,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>$86,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Shad Decker</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>51</td>
                    <td>$183,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>29</td>
                    <td>$183,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


    <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
            //    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print',
                {
                    extend: 'copy',
                    text: 'copy',
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csv',
                    text: 'csv',
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    text: 'excel',
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdf',
                    text: 'pdf',
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: 'print',
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                },

            ],        
            columnDefs: [ {
                orderable: false,
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                targets:   0,
                checkboxes : {
                    selectRow : true
                }
            } ],
            select: {
                style:    'multi',
                selector: 'td:first-child'
            },
            order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]

        } );
    } );


    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```